# backend for Socialnetworking android app with free backend affordable plan for student

Tags: android, database, parse-platform, social-networking, backend

I am creating an app which is a kinda like social network with using parse.com as a backend for my school

**Question 1**
    if u check the pricing plan  in parse https://www.parse.com/plans 
    you can see that it only allow 1 background job per second .
    Parse consider all the user using the same app as one request and i think
    there will be near 600 users using my app so they can't query at the same    time so they can't get the posts update from other

```
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.whereEqualTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " scores");
        } else {
            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

and so i can't use this method to get data and to sync with my database in the free plan but i am thinking if i just create an Asynctask and use just 
query.find() method will they still count my job as a background job.
i also found some post in stackoverflow that parse can't handle more then 10 users So my question is if i create an Asynctask and dont use parse's query.findinbackground from parse sdk "**can more people as many as 500 can synchronise the latest data that other update**"

**Question 2**
 i can't afford to pay for parse other backend plan as i am a student
if you know other backend services that can't host a social network app with free plan or at most 20$ please suggest

Comment: are you using **Parse Cloud** ?

Comment: yes i m using parse.com as cloud

Comment: i mean are you using Parse's Cloud Code module?

Comment: no haven't done any cloud code yet 
i m just afraid if it won't work and i might end up with 10 users or something like that because of their limit in free plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Introducing Background Job](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-background-jobs/)

`Background Job` Background Jobs allow you to set up long running tasks by writing code similar to Cloud Functions.
Background Job is only used when you have deployed your `Cloud Code`.

As per your code in question, It seems you are worried about the `query.inBackground()` method. Good news for you is that `query.inBackground` is like `asyncTask` not Background Job.

> There are time limits to how long Cloud Code can run, for example an
>   `afterSave` hook only has 3 seconds to run. You can use Background Jobs
>   if you need to run more time consuming processes such as data
>   migrations.

From [Advanced Background Job](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-advanced-background-jobs)